How to make the center environment in `l3doc` has the same left margin with the `Verbatim` environment?
Like the title, to use \marg and oarg commands, I have to use the center environment to surround them. But they have different left margins with the Verbatim environment, so ugly. How can I make the contents in the center environment have the same left margins as the Verbatim environment?
I would like to align all the code to the left but have the vertical skip the same as the center environment.
\documentclass{l3doc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\fvset{xleftmargin=\parindent}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{Verbatim}
    \documentclass{article}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{center}
    \cs{documentclass}\oarg{options}\marg{class}
\end{center}

\begin{Verbatim}
    \documentclass{article}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{center}
    \cs{documentclass}\oarg{options}\marg{class}
\end{center}

\end{document}



See my updated answer: You already get the same vertical spacing.

For reference, and I don't mean to offence you or anything, but: Just so you know, vertical means up and down, horizontal means left and right. I'm glad you found a helpful answer here, but from your question it really wasn't clear what you wanted to achieve.

You cannot modify the margin of a centered text, or it will be not centered anymore. On the other hand, the verbatim environment is to show the text "as is". Big end dot. So, one or another are not the right environment to format the code. Without use additional package to list code, some  option to make the verbatim centered are:

Add spaces to center the line of code manually by trial and error.
Modify \fvset accordingly by trial and error.
Do not use any environment, but the command \verb for each line in a centred paragraph.
Do not use any environment, but the command \texttt in a  centred paragraph, and use \textblacklash, escape braces, etc. The good new is that here you can break the line with \\.


\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]\par
{\bigskip\centering\verb|\documentclass{article}|\par\bigskip}
\lipsum[2][1-4]\par
{\bigskip\centering\texttt{\textbackslash documentclass\{article\}}\par\bigskip}
\lipsum[3][1-4]\par

\begin{verbatim}
                           \documentclass{article}
\end{verbatim} 

\lipsum[4][1-4]

\fvset{xleftmargin=.351\textwidth}

\begin{verbatim}
  \documentclass{article}
\end{verbatim} 

\lipsum[5][1-4]

\end{document}


I would like to align all the code to the left but have the vertical skip the same as the center environment.

@Fran LaTeX's verbatim is already a trivlist internally.

@Skillmon Very true. I lost my mind. I thinked in the  \verb command but said the environment, that already make the same vertical skips as center.

New answer regarding vertical spacing
You don't have to do anything to get the same vertical spacing around verbatim as you get in center, since they both use trivlist internally. You get the same spacing out of the box:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{l3doc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
  \cs{documentclass}\texttt{\{article\}}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\pagebreak

\lipsum[2]

\begin{verbatim}
  \documentclass{article}
\end{verbatim}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}


Old answer centering verbatim contents
The following uses enverb (disclaimer: I'm the author of that package) and varwidth to create a CenterVerb environment. It'll look (almost) like verbatim and have the block of verbatim material centred.
The enverb package features a mechanism to ignore leading spaces in the contents of the environment. By default the number of ignored symbols will be the number of character by which the matching \end is indented plus 2 more. So if you always indent your environment body by 2 spaces you'll be good to go. If you always indent them by 4 spaces use \enverbsetup{more-ignore=4}, if you don't want to indent them at all (the behaviour of LaTeX's verbatim) use \enverbsetup{auto-ignore=false}.
\documentclass{l3doc}

\usepackage{enverb,varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{CenterVerb}
  {\enverb{bol=\noindent\strut,eol=\strut\par}}
  {%
    \begin{center}
      \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
        \ttfamily\frenchspacing\raggedright
        \enverbBody
      \end{varwidth}
    \end{center}%
  }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{CenterVerb}
  \documentclass{article}
\end{CenterVerb}

\begin{center}
  \cs{documentclass}\texttt{\{article\}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \cs{documentclass}\oarg{options}\marg{class}
\end{center}

\begin{CenterVerb}
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  This is a very nice document that I created for you.
  \end{document}
\end{CenterVerb}
\end{document}



I would like to align all the code to the left but have the vertical skip the same as the center environment.

@Skyrmion in that case your question is very confusing. And the one sentence you added stating this has nothing to do with the text above it...

You can use a simple wrapper around the underlying list environment to align material left with the same vertical spacing as center. However, this will not align the material with the first non-space character of what you put in Verbatim unless you eliminate leading spaces or use an environment which strips such spaces instead.
Below cslist uses the same indentation as Verbatim, which is replaced by Verbatim* for the purpose of demonstrating alignment.
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fvset{xleftmargin=\parindent}
\pagestyle{empty}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{cslist}{}
{%
  \begin{list}{}{\leftmargin \parindent}%
    \item \relax
}{%
  \end{list}%
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{Verbatim*}
      \documentclass{article}
\end{Verbatim*}

\begin{cslist}
  \cs{documentclass}\oarg{options}\marg{class}
\end{cslist}

\begin{Verbatim*}
              \documentclass{article}
\end{Verbatim*}

\end{document}


If you want all the non-space material aligned, you have to enter the contents of Verbatim without leading spaces or use a different environment.
